# How to autosave when quitting?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

One extremely frustrating aspect of the game for me is what happens when I leave the game accidentally:

1. Most of the times, I have been changing windows for a while. From the game to the wiki, then to some kind of notepad, then back to the game;
2. At some point, I want to close other older, useless, windows to better focus;
3. The I accidentaly "ALT+F4" the Steam Window, and this closes Dwarf Fortress immediately, without saving;
4. My progress from many hours is completely thrown away in just one second.

How to make the game to ask for saving before leaving, or other measure to prevent progress loss?

**Version:** 0.50 (Steam).

Comment: Also... the reason why I already stopped playing this broken game: random crashes. And the autosave system seems related to the crashes. The only viable option in order to play the game seems to be doing manual saves like crazy... like all the time.

Comment: As for your specific issue here it doesn't seem related to Dwarf Fortress - you could just make it a habit to always close windows using the mouse. It goes slower, which is good, gives you enough time to think about what you are doing. And you can't close full screen windows with the mouse by accident either. Multiple screens help as well, if you don't have this already then maybe dig up some old crap monitor from somewhere just to drop a wikipedia browser window on it without having to tab in and out of the game.

Comment: @Amarth I cannot close windows using the mouse because I disabled windows borders on my GNU/Linux in order to save pixels of my screen from displaying actions that I can accomplish with my keyboard. My screen has a low resolution of 1366 x 768 or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by [Amarth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/220537/amarth):

> The only viable option in order to play the game seems to be doing manual saves like crazy... like all the time.

So, having no autosave when quitting, the only option is to go:

```
Settings->Game->Autosave frequency->Seasonal
```

It seems the default is "Semiannual", which is too infrequently to counter the crashes. "Yearly" isn't enough either.

"Seasonal" doesn't means "when quitting", but at least will make less game progress be lost at each game-crash or user-"oops". It's the best that can be done for now.